# How to update an array in vectorized assembly(AVX)?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, avx

```
inline void addition(double * x, const double * vx,uint32_t size){
    /*for (uint32_t i=0;i<size;++i){
        x[i] = x[i] + vx[i];
    }*/
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "1: \n\t" 

    "vmovupd    -32(%0), %%ymm1\n\t"
    "vmovupd    (%0), %%ymm0\n\t"
    "vaddpd     -32(%1), %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
    "vaddpd     (%1), %%ymm1, %%ymm1\n\t"

    "vmovupd    %%ymm0, -32(%0)\n\t"
    "vmovupd    %%ymm1, (%0)\n\t"

    "addq   $128, %0\n\t"
    "addq   $128, %1\n\t"

    "addl   $-8, %2\n\t"
    "jne    1b"
        : 
        : "r" (x),"r"(vx),"r"(size)
        : "ymm0", "ymm1"
    );
}
```

I am practicing assembly(AVX instructions) right now so I write the above piece of code in inline assembly to replace the c code in the original function(which is commented out). The compiling process is successful but when I try to run the program, An error happens: `Bus error: 10`
Any thoughts to this bug? I didn't know what's wrong here. The compiler version is clang 602.0.53. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can  ask *clang* to generate the assembly code for you (from the C code), and compare with your version?

Comment: @ringø It's almost the same, except that some labels are different and the registers are specified.

Comment: Your question is not about C, but assembler.

Comment: A few errors in the code: What's with the -32 offset?  Why add 128 to the pointers?  What happens when size is not a multiple of 8?

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for editing!

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thank you!!

Comment: Also note that `__volatile__` is wrong, but in order to get the right result, you will also need to provide the correct input/output operands.  Something like `"+m"(*x), "+r"(size) : "m"(*vx) : "ymm0", "ymm1"`

Comment: Downvoting for not including what instruction the bus error happened on, and what value was in the relevant register.  Using a debugger is essential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline assembly is a complicated beast, if you just want to practice AVX assembly use a separate asm file where you don't have to put up with the compiler. In exchange, you will need to observe calling convention though.

You have some issues with the constraints. For example, you change all your input registers without telling the compiler and that can cause all sorts of weird problems elsewhere in compiler generated code. You also need to specify a `memory` clobber for obvious reasons.

Also, learn to use a debugger so you can find the exact cause of problems and fix your own code.

Failing that, at least comment your code so we can figure out your intentions. In this case, I am particularly puzzled why you use `-32` offset to address before the array. I think you wanted `+32` there. Using two avx registers at 32 bytes each, you of course need to advance the pointers by 64 not 128. Also you have `ymm0` and `ymm1` swapped in the initial load.

This code seems to work fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

inline void addition(double * x, const double * vx,uint32_t size){
    /*for (uint32_t i=0;i<size;++i){
        x[i] = x[i] + vx[i];
    }*/
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "1: \n\t" 

    "vmovupd    32(%0), %%ymm0\n\t"
    "vmovupd    (%0), %%ymm1\n\t"
    "vaddpd     32(%1), %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
    "vaddpd     (%1), %%ymm1, %%ymm1\n\t"

    "vmovupd    %%ymm0, 32(%0)\n\t"
    "vmovupd    %%ymm1, (%0)\n\t"

    "addq   $64, %0\n\t"
    "addq   $64, %1\n\t"

    "addl   $-8, %2\n\t"
    "jne    1b"
        : "+r" (x),"+r"(vx),"+r"(size)
        :
        : "ymm0", "ymm1", "memory"
    );
}

int main()
{
    double x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    double vx[] = { 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
    int i;
    addition(x, vx, 8);
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf("%g ", x[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will appreciate, if you can give me a link to a good source to learn lldb debugger.:)

Comment: I'm your upvote. Just wanted to make the observation to @PLNewbie  (or any reader) that the sample code given will only work properly if `size` is a multiple of 8 and must be >= 8.

Comment: @PLNewbie: See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) (which I just updated with some stuff unrelated to inline asm).  It has a note about why GNU C inline asm is the hardest way to learn asm.  It's easier to write the whole function in asm yourself, or use intrinsics (and then look at the compiler output to make sure it doesn't suck).